# How to convert "weird" text to normal in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an unusual text, how to convert it to normal text with javascript?

`Nicknames, cool fonts, symbols and stylish names for Aulia – A u l i a ✿, ꧁a u l i a |ᴳᴵᴿᴸ꧂, aulia...✿, Auliaᴮᴱᴮᴬᴺ ♕, ᴬᵁᴸᴵᴬ ...`

Please help me.

Comment: Those are normal text.  They're just Unicode characters.  You can't "convert" them unless you replace them one by one.  There is no relationship between the character `ᴮ` and the character `B`.

Comment: @TimRoberts: sure there is, it's in the unicode standard.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for unicode ["compatibility normalization"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize):

```js
test = "Aulia – A u l i a ✿, ꧁a u l i a |ᴳᴵᴿᴸ꧂, aulia...✿, Auliaᴮᴱᴮᴬᴺ ♕, ᴬᵁᴸᴵᴬ ..."

console.log(test.normalize("NFKD"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options for “normal” text. As mentioned by Tim, they are just Unicode characters. You have options, both require to retrieve the [codepoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) of each character one by one:

- check value and drop anything above ASCII (that’s 255 AFAIK). You will loose data.
- build a lookup table with lookalike character. Use [this](https://gist.github.com/StevenACoffman/a5f6f682d94e38ed804182dc2693ed4b) for starters. If your codepoint is > 255, do a lookup and replace if found. Otherwise drop
- same as before, but retain the unknowns.
- finally (tongue in cheek). Make peace with Unicode. It is very inclusive